# How to change the frame of the UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I got a demand that I need to change the frame of the UIImagePickerController, but I didn't find how, so I guess maybe totally I walk into a wrong way , any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I met the same demand before, and I tried a lot and find out that, it is fixed.
Once we want to do this effect, maybe we have to build a image picker one by our own instead of using the UIImagePickerController.

Comment: Thanks, I know what I should do now.